# Android data gets deleted after Clear Data is Clicked in Manage Application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have android application in which i use **SQL Lite Database** it works fine when i save records in the database. But when i go to Manage application and clear data the all data is cleared and saved data is also lost.

Comment: I think that should be so.

Answer (score 3):

That's what *Clear all Data* is for!!!! It clears all user data written by an application (files, databases, shared preferences...)

Comment: but what should i do if i don't want my data to be get cleared any suggestions.

Comment: @user3319691 You can't prevent it. Why do you want to force this behavior?

Comment: Because user can save data related to customer in my App. which i am saving in SQL.

Comment: The user SHOULD know that *Clear All Data* will destroy all saved information.